# Why does T-SQL in SSMS run faster when wrapped in explicit transaction

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, ssms

The query simply inserts the same value 'hello' into a table 1000 times.

When this query is run in an explicit transaction - wrapping within `begin tran` and `commit tran` - it runs instantaneously. But, if the `begin tran & commit tran` statements are commented out, it takes roughly 8 seconds to complete!

Can anyone please explain?

See both the query + results below:

Explicit:

```
/*------------------------
drop table Test

create table Test (Name varchar(10))

begin tran
    set nocount on
    declare @i int = 1000

    select 'START: ', getdate() -- trick to get row title printed

    while (@i > 0)
    begin
        insert into Test (Name)
            select 'hello'
        set @i = @i - 1
    end

    select 'END: ', getdate() -- trick to get row title printed
    commit tran
------------------------*/

START:  2019-10-30 17:50:54.283  
END  :  2019-10-30 17:50:54.313
```

Implicit:

```
/*------------------------
drop table Test

create table Test (Name varchar(10))

--begin tran
set nocount on
declare @i int = 1000

select 'START: ', getdate() -- trick to get row title printed

while (@i > 0)
begin
    insert into Test (Name)
        select 'hello'
    set @i = @i - 1
end

select 'END: ', getdate() -- trick to get row title printed
--commit tran
------------------------*/

START:  2019-10-30 17:51:48.203  
END  :  2019-10-30 17:51:56.520
```

EDIT:
In my connection settings IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS = OFF. What I meant by "implicit transaction" above is simply a lack of explicit transaction.

Comment: Both are near instantaneous for me. What version of SQL Server are you using? I am on SQL Server 2014.

Comment: @Isaac,
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-GDR) (KB4505217) - 12.0.5223.6 (X64) 
 May 26 2019 20:36:50 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: )

Comment: You get these results consistently?

Comment: @Isaac yes, its between 8 - 9 secs.

Comment: You can check the actual CPU time and IO for both by prefacing each test with `SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON;` It may be the case that one batch was just waiting for another operation, but actual execution time was closer than it appeared. Worth a look, anyway.

Comment: Please don't use while loops when you can [use a tally table instead.](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1)

Answer (score 6):

SQL server needs to harden (write to disk or power protected cache) when a transaction is committed. One you use implicit trx, you have 1000 trx due to the loop and SQL needs to do 1000 ios for the trx log.

When you wrap them in one trx, sql just need to do a few ios (depends on the trx log buffer) for the trx log. SO the performance is better.

Comment: Is there a way to verify this please?

Comment: Not sure how to verify this. But you can google sql server transaction log hardening and you should find lots of articles about the technical details

Comment: @Sumith that is how it works. Each insert inside your loop must be a single ATOMic transaction. In order for this to work it has to use a transaction for each insert. Your code with the explicit transaction is doing 1000 inserts in a single transaction.

Comment: Agreed. Actually further reading seem to reveal that the question itself had some technical inconsistencies. I have IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS = OFF in the connection. ie technically implicit transactions are a different thing than what I implied in my question.

Comment: @Sumith, lack of implicit transactions is autocommit, meaing that each statement is a transaction by itself. This is different than implict transactions, which start a transaction (which can span multiple statements) and must be explictly committed.